# Bootstrap-Selectpicker: Make non-clickable years invisible and show directly given year as selected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

Following code block:

```
$(".datepicker").datepicker( {
  format: ' yyyy', // Notice the Extra space at the beginning
  viewMode: 'years',
  minViewMode: 'years',
  startDate: '-100y',
  endDate: '-17y'
});
```

outputs:

[image]

I've 2 questions:

How can I make non clickable years unvisible?

If a user types a year in the input-field and afterwards clicks this input field, the selected year should be shown as marked.

**That would be the desired result:**

[image]

Currently I am studying [the following API documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html) and could not find the related sections yet. Can someone help me? I've already done this a couple of years ago, but unfortunately I cannot remember anymore how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the API a bit but did not find this functionality, however I created a simple solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/m7atu7up/6/

We simply use CSS to hide the year spans that have the disabled class.

```
.datepicker table tr td span.disabled {
    display: none;
}
```

To style the selected span we use the following selector:

```
.datepicker table tr td span.active.active
```

This fiddle works for both your questions.

Comment: disabling works but typed year is not selected, we can forgo hide function, I'll edit my initial question and remove it.

Comment: If you type a valid year (example 1999 or 1916) the date gets selected in the calendar so I am not sure what the issue is? (updated the fiddle too)

Comment: can you maybe do following steps: 1) remove hide function (like in the edited question above) 2) click and type a valid year e.g. 1980 in the input field. 3) this typed year should be outlined with a black 1px border. At this way I can detect, which class should be modified by myself.

Comment: Aha ok, so the issue is you want to style the selected item yourself? Fiddle is updated will check for the border now.

Comment: would you please post the updated link, I still see the old one, thank you. It would be great, if we remove the blue background color and only see the outlined cell.

Comment: I updated the fiddle in the answer, to provide styling of the selected year. You have to tweak a bit yourself to get the wanted look and feel. One issue I had is the border takes space so we have to compensate with a negative margin, or else the calendars layout will get messed up.

Comment: thank you very much, yes that's it. I would change all the properties over an api which is unfortunately incomplete,..

Comment: I may award the bounty in 7 hours :)